# ORDER BY datetime depending on the day AND time

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-order-by

I have a database field of type datetime.

The name of this field is "recallDate"

I would like to order the results in the following way:

- The results must be **chronological in the time**: from newest to oldest
- The results must be **grouped by date**: in other words, result having the same date are together, grouped
- For every day, the results must be **chronological according to the hour**: earliest to latest
- The **results having no hour ( 00:00:00 ) have to be at the end of the results** of the day

This is my actual query :

```
SELECT a.recallDate, a.id, a.id_company, com.name, a.recallType 
        FROM PDT_CRM.actions a 
        INNER JOIN PDT_CRM.traders as trad on trad.id=a.id_traders 
        WHERE DATE(a.recallDate) > DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY)
        ORDER BY TIME(a.recallDate) ,  a.recallType
```

It is very likely that I have to use CASE but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: First date, then time.

Comment: post your input and expected output

Comment: Can you not get the data fixed? Practically everything sees datetimes with a 0 value as belonging at the start of the day - so which is better - to have to manually "correct" this in every query you write or change whatever's writing the data so that if it *intends* to say "midnight at the end of day X" it actually writes "midnight at the start of day X+1"?

Comment: You cannot order by newest to oldest in time and then oldest to oldest to newest in hour at the same time (if that is what you meant by "chronological according to the hour: earliest to latest"), you should add some examples

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I use PHP date functions, 
it takes a great deal of change in these functions and I don't think it's possible in the use of all functions

Comment: @jarlh You are right ! cf. Solarflar's answer

Comment: I was just trying to help you avoid issues in the future - you're assigning a *different* meaning to a date with time = 0 than most other tools will assume, by default. It means that every time you (or someone else) work with this data, you have to remember to apply a special case for those values. Under most circumstances, switching your code to using the common understanding would result in less overall work, over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to create a specific order that will put times '00:00:00' at the very end of the day:

```
...
ORDER BY date(a.rappelDate), 
         case when time(a.rappelDate) = 0 then 1 else 0 end,
         time(a.rappelDate)
```